# Export and save multiple images with a single command

Tags: plotting, export, education

I want to save multiple images, each with an appropriately assigned name, in my working directory. The images show inverse trigonometric function plots listed below:

`$InverseTrigFunctions = {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcSec, ArcCsc, ArcTan,  ArcCot, ArcSinh, ArcCosh, ArcSech, ArcCsch, ArcTanh, ArcCoth}`

`Table[DensityPlot[Im[f[(x + I y)^3]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},  ColorFunction -> "Pastel", ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Purple},  Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> Im[f[(x + I y)^3]],  Ticks -> None], {f, $InverseTrigFunctions}]`

I use the `Export` function but I cannot save the images using a single command to my working directory.

How I can do this? Using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Export`, `ToString` and string concatenation:

```
inverseTrigFunctions = {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcSec, ArcCsc, ArcTan, 
   ArcCot, ArcSinh, ArcCosh, ArcSech, ArcCsch, ArcTanh, ArcCoth};

Table[Export[ToString[f] <> "-plot.png", 
  DensityPlot[Im[f[(x + I y)^3]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Pastel", ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Purple}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotLabel -> Im[f[(x + I y)^3]], Ticks -> None]], {f,
   inverseTrigFunctions}]
```

This exports them to files with the function name first, "-plot.png" for the rest of the name.

Comment: thanks a lot for these tips @Kirma